# Bash script behaves differently from Docker run command instead of inside container itself?

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, docker

I am running the *Docker 1.0.1* client on *Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS*.  I have a container that runs a Java application in server mode.  There is a Bash script in the container that launches the server.  If I execute the bash script from inside the container's the Java application runs fine.  If I append the bash script to the end of the Docker run command and try to launch it that way, the run fails.  Checking the logs I see an error indicating the main class for the Java app could not be found.

Here's the command line:

```
$> sudo docker run -p 1566:1566 -d $USER/server /server_install/run-server.sh
```

If I remove */server_install/run-server.sh* from the command line, the container launches fine and stays resident.  But with the script file in the command line the container terminates and the logs show the error message that indicates the main Java class could not be found.  However, if I enter the container and launch *run-server.sh* from within the */server_install* directory, **it works fine**.

Do paths behave differently from inside a container's Bash shell then they do when you launch something from the command line?  Or do I have to change the current working directory to */server_install* before executing the Bash script. If so how do I do that?  That seems a little weird because the *run-server.sh* script sets up the Java path options inside of it.

Comment: Sounds like Docker isn't using the same environment variables you are (or bash isn't). I'm guessing `$PATH`. Do you have `.` in your path, set in your `.bashrc` or something, which is why it works from an interactive shell but not Docker?

Comment: Try changing your run-server.sh to just run /usr/bin/env and see what it prints in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I have to change the current working directory to /server_install before executing the Bash script. If so how do I do that?

Use the [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#workdir) directive in your `Dockerfile`.

My guess is whatever script sets your CLASSPATH takes the current working directory into consideration.

Comment: Great timing.  I just discovered the -w flag and used it to set the working directory with the Docker run command and that solved the problem, so I know you're right. But your solution would be better because then I wouldn't have to worry about the -w directive with the run command.